# SOLVED : Magento 2 : Any Specific Solution for "Front Controller Reached 100 Router Match Iterations" Error

Tags: error, controllers, magento-2.1.3

I m using magento 2.1.3. Looking Specific Solution for "Front controller reached 100 router match iterations" Error...?
I checked some answers on stackexchange but not working for magento 2.1.3.

```
public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {

    $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

    /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page */
    $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
    if (strpos($identifier, 'xyz.html') !== false) {
        $request->setModuleName('My_Module')->setControllerName('mymodule')->setActionName('index');
    }
    if (strpos($identifier, 'pqr.html') !== false) {
        $request->setModuleName('My_Module')->setControllerName('mymodule')->setActionName('testing');
    }
    $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $identifier);
}
```

Comment: It seems the error due to infinite looping.
Please share your code for more help.

Comment: router.php  code is updated.

Comment: edit your question and add as new answer your solved one.

Comment: @Rizwan Please post your updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Not Extending This Class in Controller After Extending

`\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`

And Impliments its `execute()` method it Works.

Comment: explain your answer please i m not getting you