# Magento 2 : Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento2, routing

I created custom router. But, when I run it display error.

> Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

**di.xml :**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="testRouter" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">60</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**Router.php :**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory
     */
    protected $actionFactory;

    /**
     * Event manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_eventManager;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * News factory
     *
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\TestFactory
     */
    protected $_testFactory;

    /**
     * Config primary
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     */
    protected $_appState;

    /**
     * Url
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * Response
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $_response;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory       $actionFactory [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface  $eventManager  [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface            $url           [description]
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\TestFactory           $testFactory   [description]
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager  [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface   $response      [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\TestFactory $testFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_testFactory = $testFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * Validate and Match Vendor Module and modify request
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface|null
     */
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        $condition = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['identifier' => $identifier, 'continue' => true]);
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'vendor_module_controller_router_match_before',
            ['router' => $this, 'condition' => $condition]
        );
        $identifier = $condition->getIdentifier();

        if ($condition->getRedirectUrl()) {
            $this->_response->setRedirect($condition->getRedirectUrl());
            $request->setDispatched(true);
            return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect::class);
        }

        if (!$condition->getContinue()) {
            return null;
        }

        /** @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Test $test */
        $test = $this->_testFactory->create();
        $testId = $test->checkIdentifier($identifier, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        if (!$testId) {
            return null;
        }

        $request->setModuleName('test')->setControllerName('index')->setActionName('view')->setParam('test_id', $testId);
        $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $identifier);

        return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward::class);
    }
}
```

**View.php :**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\News;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class View extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\TestFactory
     */
    protected $_testFactory;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param Context                                    $context           [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory [description]
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\TestFactory         $testFactory       [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\TestFactory $testFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_testFactory = $testFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->_request->getParam('test_id');
        $testColl = $this->_testFactory->load($id);
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $block = $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('testBlock');
        $block->setCatalogRule($testColl);
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__("Testing"));
    }
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135532/magento-2-ce-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-issue

Comment: Already so many answer tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Was Facing same issue from last 4 Hours Then i got Solution

This Might Occur Due to Many Different Reasons

1. **Incorrect Sort Order**

SortOrder of router in Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

> SortOrder Fir Router Must Be Between 31-99

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="pagesRouter" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

after that run command

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

2. **Use FronName Instead of Module Name**

i myself mistakenly wrote my module name in

```
$request->setModuleName('Vendor_ModuleName')
```

it have to Be FrontName instead od ModuleName

```
$request->setModuleName('frontname')
```

Some other Possible Solutions Are As follows

[Extending This Class in Controller After Extending](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163868/solved-magento-2-any-specific-solution-for-front-controller-reached-100-rou)